# How can i handle storage issue while writing data into cache?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching

suppose i have 3 million users and i store 100 KB/user data in cache for soft ttl 30 mins.
so at a time cache data could go 3000000x0.1 MB = 300 GB.
but my storage capacity is 100 GB.
does write policy could help me in any way ?

Comment: when you have 3 mil users, you wouldn't be having single node storage for your cache.

Comment: multiple nodes have total 100 GB.

Comment: So, increase your nodes, or rethink and reduce your per user cache to less than 100kb!